# extract tstas in a loop

Tags: matlab, regression

I am running an OLS regression with the MFE toolbox MATLAB. I want to extract the t-stats of all the 30 individual regressions. I write the following code:

```
n=30;
Tstat = zeros(1,n);
for i=1:n;
[t]=[TSTAT]=ols(Returns(:,i),X(:,:),1);
Tstat(i)=t(1);
end
```

I get the following error message: [t]=[TSTAT]=ols(Returns(:,i),X(:,:),1);
                |
Error: The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.

How do I solve this? It works perfect when I do the same for extracting the intercept constant of each of the 30 regressions. But then, one simply writes:

```
[a]=ols(Returns(:,i),X(:,:),1);
```

Comment: Why not just `Tstat(i)=ols(Returns(:,i),X(:,:),1);`?  What are you expecting to happen when you write `[t]=[TSTAT]=...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TSTAT is a vector of dimension K+1, where K is the number of independent variables, therefore the following code should be work:

```
K = length(X(1,:))  
n = 30;
Tstat = zeros(n,K+1);   # A matrix to store the n TSTAT vectors, each one of size K+1 
for i = 1:n
  [B,TSTAT] = ols(Returns(:,i),X(:,:),1);
  Tstat(i,:) = TSTAT;
end
```